# Python: How to create weighted quantiles in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand how to create simple quantiles in Pandas using [pd.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html). But after searching around, I don't see anything to create *weighted* quantiles. Specifically, I wish to create a variable which bins the values of a variable of interest (from smallest to largest) such that each bin contains an equal weight. So far this is what I have:

```
def wtdQuantile(dataframe, var, weight = None, n = 10):
    if weight == None:
        return pd.qcut(dataframe[var], n, labels = False)
    else:
        dataframe.sort_values(var, ascending = True, inplace = True)
        cum_sum = dataframe[weight].cumsum()
        cutoff = max(cum_sum)/n
        quantile = cum_sum/cutoff
        quantile[-1:] -= 1
        return quantile.map(int)
```

Is there an easier way, or something prebuilt from Pandas that I'm missing?

**Edit:** As requested, I'm providing some sample data. In the following, I'm trying to bin the "Var" variable using "Weight" as the weight. Using `pd.qcut`, we get an equal number of observations in each bin. Instead, I want an *equal weight* in each bin, or in this case, as close to equal as possible.

```
Weight  Var  pd.qcut(n=5)  Desired_Rslt
   10     1            0              0
   14     2            0              0
   18     3            1              0
   15     4            1              1
   30     5            2              1
   12     6            2              2
   20     7            3              2
   25     8            3              3
   29     9            4              3
   45    10            4              4
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, input and output that illustrates what you want?

Comment: Please, always provide sample data when asking Pandas-related questions.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think this is built-in to Pandas, but here is a function that does what you want in a few lines:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas._libs.lib import is_integer

def weighted_qcut(values, weights, q, **kwargs):
    'Return weighted quantile cuts from a given series, values.'
    if is_integer(q):
        quantiles = np.linspace(0, 1, q + 1)
    else:
        quantiles = q
    order = weights.iloc[values.argsort()].cumsum()
    bins = pd.cut(order / order.iloc[-1], quantiles, **kwargs)
    return bins.sort_index()
```

We can test it on your data this way:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'var': range(1, 11),
    'weight': [10, 14, 18, 15, 30, 12, 20, 25, 29, 45]
})

data['qcut'] = pd.qcut(data['var'], 5, labels=False)
data['weighted_qcut'] = weighted_qcut(data['var'], data['weight'], 5, labels=False)
print(data)
```

The output matches your desired result from above:

```
   var  weight  qcut  weighted_qcut
0    1      10     0              0
1    2      14     0              0
2    3      18     1              0
3    4      15     1              1
4    5      30     2              1
5    6      12     2              2
6    7      20     3              2
7    8      25     3              3
8    9      29     4              3
9   10      45     4              4
```

Comment: For a large number of quantiles, this will sometimes skip bins. I have 20 bins over a very large number of datasets, and sometimes 0.75 is missing, sometimes 0.30, etc. I do not fully understand how this code works, do you have a guess why it would skip bins?